# Keycloak: Failed to load URLs in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I'm currently trying to develop a Spring Boot Rest Api which is secured with keycloak.

I get an error when I try to call a api which the user has to be identify.

The error message is following:

```
2020-04-10 16:09:00.324  WARN 44525 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] 
o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Failed to load URLs from 
https://{{keycloakserver}}.de/auth/realms/{{realm}}/.well-known/openid-configuration

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getClient(KeycloakDeployment.java:327) [keycloak-adapter-core-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getOidcConfiguration(KeycloakDeployment.java:219) [keycloak-adapter-core-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.resolveUrls(KeycloakDeployment.java:178) [keycloak-adapter-core-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getRealmInfoUrl(KeycloakDeployment.java:232) [keycloak-adapter-core-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.createVerifier(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:107) [keycloak-adapter-core-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:47) [keycloak-adapter-core-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticateToken(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:103) [keycloak-adapter-core-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:88) [keycloak-adapter-core-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:67) [keycloak-adapter-core-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:154) [keycloak-spring-security-adapter-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:96) [keycloak-spring-security-adapter-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:97) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
```

I don't know what `Failed to load URLs from` means. I can access this side when I click on the link and the configuration file is shown.

**Setup**

Keycloak:

Keycloak Server is in the web, so no localhost.

I have a realm (test-realm) created
 
I have a client (test-client) created
I have a user (test-user) created
I have a role in the client (ADMIN) created
I have assigned the role (ADMIN) to the user (test-user)

The client protocol for the client is `openid-connect` and the access type is `confidental`.

Spring Boot:

The Spring Boot rest application is running on localhost:8080.

I added in the `applications.properties` following keycloak configs.

```
keycloak.realm={{test-realm}}
keycloak.auth-server-url = https://{{keycloakserver}}.de/auth
keycloak.resource = {{test-client}}
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
```

To make sure the test-user can only access one api call I use following config.

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/getTest")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
```

**Tests**

When I call `http://localhost:8080/getTest` with Postman I get a correct `401 Unauthorized`.

Then I called the same URL with `Authorization` and the access token of the logged in `test-user`.

With this second call I get the error message above.

Does anybody know anything about this?
If I missed a config value that you need to know, just ask.

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

SecurityConfig.java

```
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakConfiguration;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakSecurityComponents;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;

/**
 * Created by johannes on 07.04.20 for test App.
 */
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
@Configuration
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(
                new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver(KeycloakSpringBootProperties properties) {
        return new CustomKeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver(properties);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/getTest")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

CustomKeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver:

```
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment;
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder;
import org.keycloak.adapters.spi.HttpFacade;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * Created by johannes on 10.04.20 for test App.*/
@Configuration
public class CustomKeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver extends KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver {
        private final KeycloakDeployment keycloakDeployment;
    public CustomKeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver(KeycloakSpringBootProperties properties) {

        keycloakDeployment = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(properties);
    }

    @Override
    public KeycloakDeployment resolve(HttpFacade.Request facade) {
        return keycloakDeployment;
    }
}
```

TestController.java (this is just the test getter):

```
  @GetMapping("/getTest")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getTest() {

        return ResponseEntity.status(ResponseValues.ITEMDELETEFAILED.getResponseCode()).body(ResponseValues.ITEMDELETEFAILED.getResponseMessage());

    }
```

Request was made with postman, this is the code:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/getTest' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUI...' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=41E8E82178FA181817...'
```

Comment: The problem is with this `.well-known` that I believe is not of your domain. But why it is being inserted there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Issue own my own.

I noticed that my spring boot sdk was a android sdk. I don't know how this could happen.
I changed it to the java sdk, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem, and I try a lot to find the answer at google, stackoverflow etc...

Finally, I catch the clue, to make it work, just **remove the `path` of  the `keycloak.auth-server-url` as `http://192.168.0.119:8080` instead of `http://192.168.0.119:8080/auth` or something else**.

```
...   : Loaded URLs from http://192.168.0.119:8080/realms/spmia-realm/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

```
keycloak.realm=spmia-realm
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://192.168.0.119:8080
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.resource=ostock
keycloak.credentials.secret=FnUBprsgArHa7PkmR9HPWeXY0nJ22Ks1
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
keycloak.bearer-only=true
```

```yaml
...
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/keycloak
    command:
      - "start-dev"
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
...
```

```
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>18.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
...
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case: Realm name was not correct. It is case sensitive. It worked when I change it to:

```
keycloak.realm = demo
```

I had written

```
keycloak.realm = Demo
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, for me it was also connected to a flawed config value.

`keycloak.auth-server-url = https://{{keycloakserver}}.de/auth`

First I forgot the `/auth` and then I used `http` instead of `https`.

Comment: adding /auth did the trick, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I have been through this issue and solved it as follows

1- make sure of your yaml or properties file in the spring boot application

the following property should be configured based on the keycloak version you use. in my case i used v 17.0.1 and the issue arose because i added it this way
`keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth` rather than this `keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080`

but if you use a lower version than 17 it must be

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
```

please make sure that you mentioned the right host and the right port,i just mentioned localhost and the port 8080 because this my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case, I didn't recognize that there was a single whitespace at the end of my "keycloak.auth-server-url" in my application.properties file.

This way, the keycloak adapter tried to access an invalid URL.

Maybe this helps someone who has a similar issue and finds this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Please use admin panel of Keycloak. On the panel take Realm Settings and click on
OpenID Endpoint Configuration
[OpenID Endpoint Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLDQ7.png)

and you can see all endpoints:
[endpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7WNb.png)

so if your url is http://localhost:8080 end of endpoints kecloak add it yourself

Answer (score -1):

try to change `hasRole` to `hasAuthority` or add prefix `ROLE_` before the role like this `hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")`

Comment: Still the same. I get a responsecode 500 and my spring backend throws the "Failed to load URLs from https://{{keycloakserver}}.de/auth/realms/{{realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration" error

Comment: can you share the controller code and how you made the request

Comment: I updated my inital question with the code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

I had entered the wrong value for `keycloak.auth-server-url`.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers. *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*