# Spring Boot Keycloak Failed to load URLs from

Tags: spring, docker, networking, dns, keycloak

I'm currently working on a RESTful-API in Spring-Boot. The API is secured with Spring Security and Keycloak.

The programm is running insde a Docker-Container. The Keycloak-Service is running on an extra server and beeing used by other services.

Now everything worked fine until tried to deploy the new version on the server. I always get the same exception "Failed to load URLs from".

I can reach the URL with my webbrowser.
The Strange thing is that if i use the same Image on my local-machine every thing works just fine.

I checked for potential spelling errors but couldn't find any.

Could there by any Docker-Configuration i missed?

##### Update

I tried to run the same Image on an new Instance(Same Specs as the above) and i get the same Error. I think it has something to do with the dns.

Server: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Local-Machine: Windows 10 / Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Spring-Boot: 2.3.9.RELEASE
JAVA: 11
Keyclaock: 12.0.4

### Exception

```java
2021-06-16 21:01:35.903  WARN 1 --- [http-nio-8082-exec-1] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Failed to load URLs from https://***.ma.bw-cloud-instance.org/auth/realms/socken-shop/.well-known/openid-configuration

java.net.UnknownHostException: ***.ma.bw-cloud-instance.org: Temporary failure in name resolution
    at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1519) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1368) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1302) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getOidcConfiguration(KeycloakDeployment.java:221) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-12.0.4.jar!/:12.0.4]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.resolveUrls(KeycloakDeployment.java:179) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-12.0.4.jar!/:12.0.4]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getRealmInfoUrl(KeycloakDeployment.java:237) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-12.0.4.jar!/:12.0.4]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.createVerifier(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:107) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-12.0.4.jar!/:12.0.4]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:47) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-12.0.4.jar!/:12.0.4]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticateToken(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:103) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-12.0.4.jar!/:12.0.4]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:88) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-12.0.4.jar!/:12.0.4]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:67) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-12.0.4.jar!/:12.0.4]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:154) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-12.0.4.jar!/:12.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:96) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-12.0.4.jar!/:12.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke(AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.java:67) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-12.0.4.jar!/:12.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:181) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-12.0.4.jar!/:12.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

#### Dockerfile

```yaml
# Use as anchor image
FROM openjdk:11-jdk
# Define a work directory
WORKDIR /deployments/
# Add the application
ADD target/rest_controller.jar /deployments/app.jar
# This command will be executed at container startup
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

#### Application properties

```
# Keyclaok
keycloak.realm=${kc.realm}
keycloak.resource=${kc.resource}
keycloak.auth-server-url=${kc.url}
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.public-client=false
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.credentials.secret=${kc.client.secrete}
keycloak.cors=true
```

#### Maven Profile

```
<profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <!-- Keycloak stuff -->
                <kc.realm>socken-shop</kc.realm>
                <kc.resource>socken-api</kc.resource>
                <kc.url>https://****.ma.bw-cloud-instance.org/auth</kc.url>
                <kc.client.secrete>***</kc.client.secrete>
            </properties>
</profile>
```

#### Keyclaok Object (Using)

```
private Keycloak keycloakProvider() {
        Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl(keycloakURL)
                .realm(keycloakRealm)
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .clientId(keycloakClient)
                .clientSecret(keycloakSecrete)
                .build();
        keycloak.tokenManager().getAccessToken();
        return keycloak;
    }
```

#### Security Config

```
 @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");
        // grantedAuthorityMapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true);

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthorityMapper);
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**/admin/**").hasRole("Admin")
                .antMatchers("/**/customer/**").hasRole("Customer")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable(); //TODO 
    }
```

Comment: More code/configuration might be usefull to help you and this could help [keycloak-failed-to-load-urls-in-spring-boot-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142611/keycloak-failed-to-load-urls-in-spring-boot-application)

Comment: @Lautre I added everything sorounding keycloak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the the serverporvider has issues with their internal network-structure. It cant resolve any address or it gives the wrong one.