# Failed to load URLs from https://example.com/auth/realms/REALM/.well-known/openid-configuration

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, pkix

I was using my spring-boot service with `keycloak` for login. Until yesterday I had a keycloak on localhost:8081, but today we have been given a new domain for Keycloak (https://example.com) instead of still using ***localhost:8081***.
For this I had to update my 'etc/hosts' file with the new domain.

The problem is that I can't launch any request from my microservice. I have a controller, with many end-points, but I can't access any of them, I get the error:

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

with this Warning:

```
Failed to load URLs from https://example.com/auth/realms/REALM/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

However, from Postman I can access this URL: *https://example.com/auth/realms/REALM/.well-known/openid-configuration*

In theory, I have my application.yaml well configured with the `keycloak` settings (I only had to change the auth path, where before it was localhost, is now my `https://example.com`)

```
keycloak.auth-server-url: https://example.com/auth/
keycloak.realm: MyREALM
keycloak.resource: login
keycloak.public-client: true
keycloak.credentials.secret: mysecret
```

I accessed my keycloak (with the new domain), I tried to export the certificate and with Keytools integrate it in the 'cacerts' file but I haven't been able to get it to work.

I've tried following these articles, but they don't solve my problem:

[Keycloak: Failed to load URLs in Spring Boot Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142611/keycloak-failed-to-load-urls-in-spring-boot-application)

["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)

Why is my microservice giving me this error?

```
2022-07-20 12:03:28.013 WARN 25996 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment : Failed to load URLs from https://example.com/auth/realms/MyREALM/.well-known/openid-configuration

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:370) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:313) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: It looks like your https://example.com has misconfigured TLS (HTTPS). For example it is uses Let's Encrypt CA, but it doesn't expose intermediate LE certificates.

Comment: How Can I configurated TLS to expose LE certificates? @JanGaraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read many info about the `certificates`, download certificates of `HTTPs` web and add it to the `cacerts` file but it doesn't work for me.

The solution (temporally) was:

The problem with `certificates` was only in mi localhost, not in the development environment.
Then, in local, I opened a `port-forward` connection with `Keycloak` service, which throws the `certificates-exception`. It cans allowed me don't attack directly to the domain from Spring-Boot, avoiding the certificates error.

```
port-forward service/keycloak 8081:8080
```